# Retrieve Country Telephone Area Code using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, phone-number, country-codes

I want to retrieve the country telephone code using ASP.NET C#... I've searched at google and the MSDN website but what I've found was the way how to retrieve the ISO Country Code..

Comment: How is this + a Dictionary not enough? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

Comment: Here's the scenario: I wanted to retrieve the telephone code everytime the user visits my website... not only in the philippines but any country.

Comment: So you have an internet website and you want to get the anonymous user's telephone code from his IP?

Comment: yeah.. absolutely.. that was my task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything built in.
You can use some web service to aquire this information, such as this one: http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso

Comment: It would have been nice if you also have shown how to call this webservice from code.

Comment: Tim - Add http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL as a service reference, and than use it as though it was an ordinary DLL reference.